# What is user_location permission scope?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Reading [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) about `user_location` permission. I see app will get logged in user's city info. But what about other users? If I fetch members of a Facebook event, will I get their city info too?

Comment: No. `user_location` is that the user grant your app access to their location. No one can grant access to other peoples location

Comment: Why is that I can search for users in Facebook, sometimes I can see their location, but fetching info with Facebook Graph API will not provide location?

Comment: Because Facebook.com is not the API.

Comment: I though I can get anything with API what I can get from Facebook.com

Comment: That is not true.